# Weird behavior of back button for fragments within fragments

Tags: xamarin.android

Hi I have a navigation drawer and am showing fragments based on selection from the navigation drawer. I have a tab layout along with view pager in majority of my fragments. And coming to the weird behavior, in one of the tabs I'm having to again switch fragments based on user behavior which is working as expected but when I press the back button the whole fragment is getting popped instead of the child fragments being popped first.

This is how I'm populating the tabbed fragment from mainActivity

```
fragment = new EquipmentFragment();
SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                        .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
                        .AddToBackStack(null).Commit();
```

This is how I've setup the tabLayout and viewPager

```
TabLayout tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tab_layout);
_viewpager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
SetupViewPager(_viewpager);
tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(_viewpager);
```

This is how I'm switching fragments within one of my tabs

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
 transaction.AddToBackStack(null);
 transaction.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
 transaction.Commit();
```

but pressing on back button results in the whole tabbedFragment being popped instead of the child items being popped first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the "OnBackPressed" and the "OnOptionsItemSelected" and check, and here you need to handle the back navigation - determine whether to pop from ChildFragmentManager, FragmentManager, or finish the activity.

It could look something like this:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        var didPopFromFragment = TryPopFromFragment();
        if (didPopFromFragment == false)
        {
            Finish();
        }
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                var didPopFromFragment = TryPopFromFragment();
                if (didPopFromFragment)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool TryPopFromFragment()
    {
        var hasChildFragments = yourFragment.ChildFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0;
        if (hasChildFragments)
        {
            yourFragment.ChildFragmentManager.PopBackStack();
        }

        return hasChildFragments;
    }
```

... hope it helps.